# Infinite generator in Python for days of week

Tags: python, generator

I have seen similar questions, my is little bit more practical, I would like to iterate over range of week days over and over again.

So far my iterator is not cyclic, help me please to resolve this.

```
def day_generator():
    for w in ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']:
        yield w;

g = day_generator()
print g.next()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use itertool's cycle:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle

```
import itertools
def day_generator():
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    for day in itertools.cycle(days):
        yield day
```

Long story short(and as mentioned in comments) it is really enough to make:

```
day_generator = itertools.cycle(days)
```

Thanks @FlavianHautbois

Comment: Your code is not valid Python, your function has no arguments... Plus you use a function for nothing, you could have just written `day_generator = itertools.cycle(days)`

Comment: Yes, I tried to adapt my code to mentioned in the answer. Will update it to reduce confusing. 
I think that main point here is `cycle` method

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) does exactly what you want:

```
import itertools

day_generator = itertools.cycle(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, you just needed to put your "yield" statement in an endless loop, so that it will always wrap around when needed:

```
def day_generator():
    while True:
        for w in ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']:
            yield w

g = day_generator()
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(g))

##Output:
##
##    Monday
##    Tuesday
##    Wednesday
##    Thursday
##    Friday
##    Saturday
##    Sunday
##    Monday
##    Tuesday
##    Wednesday
```

However, as others have noted, `itertools.cycle` is the most concise way to do it.